# I want to create a "global" screen wake listener that stays active in all activities.. how do I go about doing this?

Tags: android

I want my app to be globally aware that the screen has come out of sleep mode.

I can put this code into every activity class

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "screen woke up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
```

But I don't want it listening in the background multiple times when multiple activities are active.

How would I go about setting this up so every activity shares the same "listener" if that makes sense?

Comment: You can register a broadcast receiver in your manifest so that you don't have to worry about registering/unregistering it within your activities.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  I wrote a class that extends Application, and then added that in my manifest.  `<Application android:name="com.blahblah.myclass" >`